# successful live chat in botium is not working as testcase/testset

Tags: testing, automated-tests, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I've integrated Botium box with my Watson Assistant chatbot, however  exported live chat's testcase is failing to run successfully even though my live chat worked just fine.

I would expect that the testcase that can be saved as a testcase should work fine, when live chat conversation flowed smoothly, without any other intent matches.

Is there a way to bypass a failed test case in a conversational testset, since i know that it is a false positive.

Comment: pls attach generated convo file and testcase failure. log output will help as well. no idea what the problem is based on your text.

Comment: I actually want to mark a failed testcase as false positive, because text that bot sends is EXACTLY the same as expected text. I'm unable to post the logs(this is really sensitive data..), we have dialog in watson which we wants to test not just the intents. for this I have interacted with the bot after connecting to it from Bottom Box chatbot's section from the beginning to till the end of the dialog and exported my chat as a testset, now that test set when ran against the same chatbot that I've interacted with failing. hope this gives some insight. Thanks.

Comment: yes, it gives insights, but if this would be a generic problem it would already have been fixed. you can transmit sensitive data to florian.treml @ botium.at